# How to access child component's methods inside other components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a reusable component's which I want to use it inside any component I want:

reusable.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="example">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    alertme() {
      console.log("hey!");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In another component I want to use this component's (reusable.vue) methods and data .. etc

```
<template>
    <reusable>

        <template slot-scope="defaultSlotScope">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="alertme">click me!</button>
        </template>

    </reusable>
</template>

<script>
import reusable from "../reusable.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    reusable
  }
};
</script>
```

Iam getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "alertme" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

Which mean Vue  doesn't recognize this method (alertme)..

So how can I make this works ?

Comment: I have posted an answer, did it worked for you? Looking forward to hear your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a problem of [Compilation Scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope), in which your attempt to use a method of a child component cannot be achieved because it's usage belongs to the parents compilation scope not the child's.

To solve that and enable communication between parent-child you should send message with events as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events).

Here below it's a possible solution:

**reusable.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="example" v-on:my-event="alertme">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    alertme() {
      console.log("hey!");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Component using **reusable.vue**

```
<template>
    <reusable>

        <template slot-scope="defaultSlotScope">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('my-event')">click me!</button>
        </template>

    </reusable>
</template>

<script>
import reusable from "../reusable.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    reusable
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it did the trick .. another question In my mind: what if there is some data in "reusable" and in another component I want to loop through it and display it inside it !?